Error when attempting to install pytest-playwright
I receive this error message in the terminal of visual studio code.
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet Failed to build greenlet ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (greenlet)
This is the command that I ran to install playwright and pytest:
pip install pytest-playwright

Does this answer your question? Playwright installation Error. pip install playwright gives ''No matching distribution"

the error is while installing greenlet, a dependency for pytest-playwright. Try installing greenlet directly: pip install greenlet, and if you can't troubleshoot yourself, update your post with the exact and complete error message.

It gives me the same error message.
